# Отменить событие по клику

Tags: jquery, menu, navigationbar, toggle, hide

**Задача:** при клике на кнопку, открывать меню, а при повторном клике на эту же кнопку, а так же любое другое пространство в документе, закрывать его.

Для этого, имеется вызов меню по кнопке:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toggle").click(function () {
        $(".vertical_nav").slideToggle("300");
    });
});
```

Так же присутствует функция закрытия по клику вне меню:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).mouseup(function (e){ 
        var div = $(".vertical_nav"); 
        if (!div.is(e.target) 
            && div.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
            div.hide(); 
        }
    });
});
```

**Проблема:** если клик происходит по кнопке вызова меню **при уже открытом меню**, оно не закрывается (что требуется) а открывается заново.

**Вопрос:** как при уже открытом меню заставить его закрываться при клике на кнопку вызова.

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/192304/

*(При этом интересен вариант именно с использованием двух разных функций, т.к. функцию закрытия можно будет повесить на различные элементы, которые так же могут потребовать исчезновения по клику вне элемента)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас по клику считывается событие и по body, и по ссылке + нужно использовать slideToggle() метод для закрытия/открытия dom элемента.
Вот рабочий код

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".toggle").click(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(".vertical_nav").slideToggle("300");
            });
            $(document).click(function (e){ 
                var div = $(".vertical_nav"); 
                if (!div.is(e.target) 
                    && div.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
                    div.hide(); 
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Благодарю! А возможно ли сделать это с двумя разными функциями? Или такой вариант не получится.

Comment: Я думаю можно такое провернуть ч/з toggleClass и проверять какой класс сейчас у элемента. Или же присваивать boolean значение переменной и проверять его, а затем вызывать ту или иную функцию.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз!